# Rendering issues of umlauts on Wildfly server on certain machines

Tags: angular, wildfly, diacritics

When I run the wildfly server and the application, the German umlauts are getting rendered on my machine perfectly fine. 
One of my colleague who has the same config machine and same installation files required for the application to run, does not render the umlauts. It renders the question marks symbol. 
We both have same charset imported in the header of the html pages. 
The browser versions are the same. 
The language pack for the computer is also the same.

Can anyone shed a light on this issue? What might be the problem? 
Is there a load order we should follow for importing the charsets? 
Or maybe should we make any changes in the standalone.xml config file?

Please ask any questions if you feel the above information is incomplete.

Thanks